# HAProxy one port down failover all ports

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to implement HAProxy for auto-failover for several ports. Like to have the capability to auto-failover all ports, such as 389, 443, and 8443 if any one of these ports is down.

Looks to me the following configuration only auto-failover on a port not all ports.

```
mode tcp
server s1 10.10.10.1:389 check inter 1s fail 3 rise 3
server s2 10.10.10.2:389 check backup
```

Thanks,

Comment: Don't use `check backup` but instead simply `backup`, this way you have more availability. And welcome the site! :)

Answer (score 1):

Write a simple script that for a given server checks all three  ports and which will return a non-zero error condition when either one or more  port/service fails.

Configure and use that script as an [`external-check command </path/to/scriptname>`](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#external-check%20command)  for all your services instead of the native checks.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look at it. Appreciated.

Comment: I tried external-check. Somehow, I can't make it work. Here is the message I got when I check the script. Looks like I have some chroot issue? ubuntu@ip-10-205-233-157:/etc/haproxy$ haproxy -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -c
[ALERT] 050/161903 (21641) : Proxy 'esa_ldap' : 'option external-check' unable to find required 'global.external-check'.
[ALERT] 050/161903 (21641) : Fatal errors found in configuration.

Comment: Have you tried using an  absolute path to the script global.external-check?